# What are the limitations of a Powerpoint master page text placeholder?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I've been tasked with creating a Powerpoint template that matches existing templates created in InDesign and Keynote. I'm running into what appears to be limitations of master page text placeholders. I'm familiar with Adobe software but not super skilled when it comes to Powerpoint. (I'm using version 16.36 for Mac) Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to format a master page text placeholder to have only part of the text in bold? When I've attempted this, it shows up correctly on the master page but when you create a new slide, that formatting disappears from the text box.
2. Is there a way to force a master page text placeholder to show more than one bullet/paragraph when you create a new slide from that master page. I created a text placeholder with multiple example bullets or multiple example paragraphs, but when I add a new slide using that master page layout it only shows the first bullet or first paragraph from the text placeholder.

I can't post images, but the links below are screenshots of the difference between the master page and the slide created from that master page. The ideal outcome is that they look identical.

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fkmN.png]

Answer (score 0):

> > Is it possible to format a master page text placeholder to have only part of the text in bold?

No.

> > Is there a way to force a master page text placeholder to show more than one bullet/paragraph when you create a new slide from that master page. I created a text placeholder with multiple example bullets or multiple example paragraphs, but when I add a new slide using that master page layout it only shows the first bullet or first paragraph from the text placeholder.

No, but when you think about it, this makes sense; you wouldn't want to have to force the user to delete all that extra text if only one bullet point is wanted.

The usual way to handle this type of situation would be to provide example slides in the template and instructions to either delete the examples or to copy and use them to fill in the desired text.